# Difference between "transfer learning" and "fine-tuning"

Tags: natural-language, transformers, language-models

I am currently reading the [BERT paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf) and it splits the use of pre-trained models into **two categories**:

- **Feature-based** whereby you just take the embeddings for the tokens and plug it into whatever problem you want
- **Fine-tuning** where you add a couple of task-specific layers at the end of the pretrained model and then just run a couple of training epochs on that.

But in section **2.3** they mention transfer learning as if it were something different from "fine-tuning".

What is the difference (if any) between **transfer learning** and just **fine-tuning** as applied to LMs and downstream tasks?

Comment: Fine tuning is just one way of doing transfer learning. Indeed, they mention fine-tuning in Sec 2.3 (which is a related work section).

Comment: I think the first approach is based on feature extraction, where you extract features from a pretrained model and use it as input of a (usually smaller) task-spefic network. In finetuning instead you add layers on top the pre-trained model and train the whole network with respect to a task-specific loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both terms are used as near-synonyms nowadays, but there is a slight difference.

- Transfer learning is a machine learning paradigm where you adapt a model trained for one task (in the case of BERT, it is masked language modeling) to **perform another task** (e.g., question answering)
- Finetuning means training a neural network (or only a sub-network) on a **smaller dataset** than the main training procedure, typically with a **smaller learning rate** and often using a different training objective. This is how transfer learning is done in the BERT paper.

There are instances of transfer learning without fine-tuning and vice versa. A popular way of transfer learning with Transformer is [Adapters](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.00751), which adds small subnetworks, but does not involve finetuning. Finetuning on artificially noised data is a common training step when training machine translation models (so they can handle typos). However, it is not transfer learning because the task is still the same.